# What does fake_time += 60 in rspec mean?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm going through an rspec tutorial on using "Time."  Can someone explain what the following code means?

```
it "takes exactly 1 second to run a block that sleeps for 1 second (with stubs)" do
  fake_time = @eleven_am
  Time.stub(:now) { fake_time }
  elapsed_time = measure do
    fake_time += 60  # adds one minute to fake_time
  end
  elapsed_time.should == 60
end
```

I get it's suppose to take 60 seconds, but technically I'm just adding 60 seconds to the time variable `fake_time`, which should be instantaneous.  Why does it take 60 seconds?

And here's the code for the `measure` function, which I wrote.  It's suppose to measure how long it takes to run a block of code.

```
def measure
  m1 = Time.now
  num.times { yield }
  m2 = Time.now
  m2 - m1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This test is using basic [stubbing](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/frames).  It doesn't make the method take extra time - it simply modifies the 'stubbed' value that would be returned by `Time.now`.  This is useful for testing to ensure that after a certain amount of time 'would have elapsed', the expected values will be returned.